# Is there a way to use SYSDATE with a weekly date?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I've been trying to fetch some daily data with SYSDATE on a date type YYYYMMDD as following:

```
SELECT dates, trunc(calendar_date, 'DD') calendar_dates, weekday_nbr
FROM db.date
WHERE dates BETWEEN to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-2, 'YYYYMMDD') AND to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

But now I'm trying to use the same but on a YYYY+MM+Week date type with not much success

I tried using:

```
SELECT T time, period, fiscal_week
FROM db.time
WHERE time BETWEEN to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-2, 'W') AND to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1,'W')
```

With time as a 7 digit number, and period and fiscal week as a 2 digit number

Knowing that there's no way I can truncate such date type, how can TRUNC SYSDATE YYYY+MM+Week to get the data on the last 2 weeks?

Also I was thinking about maybe getting the totals from a set day and then dropping all but the last 2 weeks, but on the long run maybe that would be time consuming.

Comment: please edit the question and show all table DDL with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

> Knowing that there's no way I can truncate such date type, how can TRUNC SYSDATE YYYY+MM+Week to get the data on the last 2 weeks?

Assuming that your fiscal weeks are from Monday-Sunday then you can truncate to the start of the ISO week (which is always Midnight on Monday) and use that for the basis of the comparison:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   db.time
WHERE  dates >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '14' DAY
AND    dates <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
```

---

If you have a column that is for weeks then you should still use a `DATE` data type and add a `CHECK` constraint (and can use virtual columns to generate the week and the year):

```sql
CREATE TABLE time (
  dt    DATE
        CHECK (dt = TRUNC(dt, 'IW')),
  year  NUMBER(4,0)
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt)),
  month NUMBER(2,0)
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt)),
  week  NUMBER(1,0)
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FLOOR((dt - TRUNC(dt, 'MM'))/7) + 1),
  time  VARCHAR2(7)
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
          CAST(
            TO_CHAR(dt, 'YYYYMM')
            || (FLOOR((dt - TRUNC(dt, 'MM'))/7) + 1)
             AS VARCHAR2(7)
          )
        )
  -- ...
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ei67ejfE)

Then you can use the logic above on the date column.

---

If you do not have a `DATE` column then you will need to convert your `YYYYMMW` number into a `DATE` and then use the logic above.

For example, if the logic for your fiscal weeks (which you have not described) is that the first week of each month starts on the first Monday of the month then you can convert the `YYYYMMW` number to a `DATE` using:

```sql
SELECT NEXT_DAY(
         TO_DATE(SUBSTR(time, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM') - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         'MONDAY'
       ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (SUBSTR(time, 7, 1) - 1) AS week_start
FROM   db.time
```

and then could use it to filter the table using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         NEXT_DAY(
           TO_DATE(SUBSTR(time, 1, 6), 'YYYYMM') - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           'MONDAY'
         ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (SUBSTR(time, 7, 1) - 1) AS week_start
  FROM   db.time t
)
WHERE  week_start >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '14' DAY
AND    week_start <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
```

If you have different logic for calculating when fiscal weeks start then you will need to apply that logic to the conversion.

Comment: With this query I get the error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE in the 3rd line , column 17, right before the trunc happens the error.

Comment: @JoshuaAra Then use whatever column has a `DATE` data type. You have not provided a [MRE] with a `CREATE TABLE` statement in your question so we have to guess what things mean. If you are working with dates then you should use a `DATE` data type and not numbers.

Comment: @MT0 Looks like they have date-like numbers in `YYYYMMW` format in the `time` column